1970's TV movie about a robbery with a heat-triggered alarm system
I'm looking for a movie about a high-end robbery of jewels or artwork. The robbery took place (I believe) at the home of a wealthy owner as opposed to a business/gallery.  The burglar alarm system is advanced, and temperature-sensitive - a temperature of 193 degrees Fahrenheit renders the alarm useless.  (A memorable specific detail.)  The break-in occurs through a window, and some special heating devices (heat lamps?) raise the air temperature in the room containing the items of interest to avoid setting off the alarm.
I believe two individuals (a man and woman) pulled off the robbery successfully without tripping the alarm.  Due to the high heat, they strip their clothing to a minimum, and have a love scene in the super-heated room.
Crime drama/suspense, probably dates back to the late 1970’s.  

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification.What time period was it about? What country was it likely from? What language? Are there any other details you remember, recognisable actors or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

I think someone asked this before.

After some digging, the movie is "A Fine Pair" starring Rock Hudson and Claudia Cardinale (1968). About 40 minutes in, the pair puts a combustible mixture into the heating system to superheat the room to 194 degrees.  The pair find the safe to take care of the business at hand (to put stolen jewels back); the room has a reddish hue.  The movie is on DVD. 

Good work. You can mark this answer as accepted (checkmark on the left) to wrap up the question.
